# Is Kusha (kush) son of Lord Rama?

Tags: ramayana, rama

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama#Children), Lord Rama and Sita have twins named Lava (Luv) and Kusha (Kush). From childhood I have also learnt that Lord Rama had twins. While reading [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/646/who-are-the-children-of-vishnu-and-lakshmi) question, I came across [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/646/who-are-the-children-of-vishnu-and-lakshmi/648#comment1278_646) comment that mentions that Kusha was made by Valmiki as a clone to Lava and that Lord Rama has only one son Lava. Can anyone clarify which of these is true?

Comment: It is absurd who ever said this, it is just absurd

Comment: I remember having read the comment previously. But I cannot find it now..

Comment: Keep searching for truth. It's waiting for u to discover. But be prepared to except it or else it will mess up mind. The scholar of today writers give great dicovery of our religions. Quick tempered minded people should not be involved further studies. We r now about 80years of freedoms and able to express great lord from gean pool. Try to master shiva Puranas and all answer one seeks will be prvovided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Of course he is**. The Ramayana says Sita gave birth to two sons, not that Vamiki cloned one from the other:

> *yāmeva rātriṃ śatrughna parṇaśālāṃ samāviśat
>
>   tāmeva rātriṃ sītāpi prasūtā dārakadvayam* [VRM - 7.66.1]
>
> **Meaning**
>   On the same night in which Satrughna took shelter in the hermitage,  Sita gave birth to two sons.

That same chapter then goes on to describe how the two sons get the name of Lava and Kusha.  After the birth of the sons, the disciples there informed Valmiki of this and told to protect the new born children from ghosts and demons.

So Valmiki took a grass (*Kusha*), cut it off (*lava*) into two parts and sanctified it with *mantras*. He instructed the women there to rub the upper part to the elder boy and the lower part to the younger boy. That is how they came to be known as Lava and Kusha. [7.66.4-7]

So some probably take that ritual that Valmiki did to save the new born twins from the effect of ghosts, demons etc. as a cloning process, but it is not. As evident from the scripture, **Sita gave birth to two sons, there were no clones made by Valmiki.**

Comment: Thanks for the reference and details. I knew it but wanted to clarify it as I am newbie in terms of religion.

Comment: @Srikanth yes it's fine, there are so many variations and stories that sometimes it creates doubt as to which one is true.

Comment: @BeHappy Can you tell from where you source your slokas? You seem to have both the sloka and translation for most of the Itihasas and Puranas.

Comment: @Surya Be Happy hasn't been on the site since April.  But you can read the Valmiki Ramayana in Sanskrit here: http://vedicilluminations.com/downloads/Ramayana/itx%20sanskrit/ It's in ITRANS, but you can convert it to Devanagari using this website: http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Lava and Kusha are definitely both sons of Rama and Sita.  The birth of Lava and Kusha in the ashram of the sage Valmiki is described in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/dKC5) from the Uttara Kanda of the Ramayana:

> On the same night Satrughna housed himself in a thatch-cottage **Sita gave birth to twin sons**. In the midnight 
>   the Muni boys came to Valmiki and communicated unto him 
>   is auspicious intelligence, saying "O illustrious Sir, the 
>   loved spouse of Rama hath given birth to two sons ; do 
>   thou so protect them that evil spirits might not injure them." 
>   Hearing aring those words the highly effulgent Valmiki went there 
>   and attained to great delight on beholding those two highly 
>   effulgent sons, resembling the newly risen sun and the celestials.
>
> Thereupon he made arrangements against the oppression of ghosts and goblins. Thereupon taking Kusa (the upper part of the grass) and Lava (the lower part) the great 
>   ascetic Valmiki made those arrangements. And giving 
>   Kusa sanctified by Mantras unto the hands of elderly women 
>   he said, "do ye rub the person of the elder boy with these" ; 
>   and giving them Lava he said "do ye rub the person of the 
>   younger brother with this. And according to this I shall 
>   name the first Son Kusa and the second Lava ; and by those 
>   names they shall be celebrated on earth."

And just so that there's no doubt that Rama is the father, here is what Valmiki tells Rama about the paternity of Lava and Kusha, in [another excerpt](http://gdurl.com/xcR6) from the Uttara Kanda of the Ramayana:

> I tell you the truth, O Rama, that these irrepressible twin 
>   brothers are your sons, O descendant of Raghu. I am 
>   the tenth son of Pracheta, so, far from speaking untruth 
>   it does not even spring up in my mind. I therefore 
>   know the truth that these twins are thy sons.