# Why did Vishnu need to incarnate as the son of Jamadagni to defeat Sahastrarjuna? Why not just kill him himself (using his true form)?

Tags: vishnu, mahabharata, vaishnavism, indra

The question is based on this quote from Mahabharata ([Vana Parva Section 115](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03115.htm))

> And grown resistless by the virtue of a granted boon, he ever mounted
>   on that car, trampled upon gods and Yakshas and saints on all sides
>   round. And all the born beings wheresoever placed, were harassed by
>   him. Then **the celestials and the saints of a rigidly virtuous life,
>   met together, and thus spake to Vishnu**, the god of gods, the slayer of
>   demons, and possessed of prowess that never failed, saying. 'O blessed and revered lord, for the purpose of preserving all the born beings,
>   it is necessary that Arjuna should be killed by thee.' And the mighty
>   ruler of the Haihaya tribe placing himself on his celestial car,
>   affronted Indra, while that deity was enjoying himself with Sachi, his
>   queen. Then, O Bharata's son, the blessed and **the revered god
>   (Vishhnu) held a consultation** with Indra, **with a view to
>   destroying Kartavirya's son**. And on that occasion, all that was for
>   the good of the world of beings, was communicated by the lord of gods;
>   and the blessed god worshipped by the world, to do all that was
>   necessary, went to the delightful Vadari wood which was his own chosen
>   **retreat for practising penances**.

Did people start considering Kartavirya Sahastrarjuna a Rakshasa? Vayu Purana also labeled him as a good righteous king but Mahabharata says that he was a evil king. And if so, then why did not Visnu kill him the moment he harassed the Devas?

Comment: The purpose of Parshurama incarnation was not only to Kill Sahastrarjuna. If this was the first and last purpose of this incarnation of Lord Vishnu then what Parshurama doing on Earth till now? Every incarnation of Lord Vishnu has many reasons to incarnate and many those reasons also which can't be understand by anyone. If you read whole story about Parshurama then you will come to know then after defeating Sahastarjuna, Parshurama did many more great deeds. Even till now Purpose of Parshurama incarnation hasn't over that's why he is still alive and waiting for right time to show up.

Comment: Rishabha you can write the answer based on Bhagvat or other puranas , where the exact purpose of lord vishnu's avatar  is mentioned.

Comment: The purpose of my question is to know why Vishnu needed to become an avatar to defeat Sahastrarjun. Sahastrarjun was harassing the Devas and Indra/Sachi. Yet Vishnu would not take care of Sahastarjun himself.

Comment: From this Related Question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8518/12304 : Vishnu curses Sudarshana to be born on Earth, saying something like "You will be born as a powerful king, and you will have the same thousand arms that you currently have. I will be born as the mere son of a sage, and I will defeat you."

Comment: I do not trust any of the Puranas. For me only Mahabharata and Ramayana are authentic.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: Good question