# Why is Shiva and Parvati depicted with their children but not Vishnu and Lakshmi?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi

We often find pictures of Shiva and Parvati together with their children i.e. Ganesha and Kartikeya/Murugan.
[image]

However, we never find pictures of Vishnu and Lakshmi with their son Kamadeva. Why is it so?

Comment: Thanks, it's actually a question of my friend Arkaprabha Majumdar who's an ex user on this site (user 9072). @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately he left so he asks me to clear his doubts through my account. @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Kamadeva is not son of Vishnu and Lakshmi. But yes, incarnation of Kamadeva (Pradyumna) was son of Krishna and Rukmani. correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: I am not aware of any children of this couple. If you have any references please let me know.

Comment: @Wikash_ [Who are the children of Vishnu and Lakshmi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/646/5212)

Comment: [Duplicate?] https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/646/93